# C++ ADO.NET Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm trying to insert some lines in database, but I got an error while executing this code :

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <system.data.dll>
#using <System.Xml.dll>

#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

// This is the entry point for this application
int _tmain(void)
{
    SqlConnection      ^ mySQLConnection;
    SqlDataAdapter     ^ myDataAdapter;
    DataSet            ^ myDataSet;
    DataRow            ^ myRow;
    SqlParameter       ^ myParameter;

    try
    {
        mySQLConnection = gcnew SqlConnection("Data Source=NECTARYS-PC;Initial Catalog=MonitoringN;Integrated Security=True;");
        myDataAdapter = gcnew SqlDataAdapter();
        myDataSet = gcnew DataSet();

        // Open up the connection
        mySQLConnection->Open();

        myDataAdapter->SelectCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("select motif,dateAlerte,fixee,nomPoste," +
        "nomApplication,nomFichier,FichierModel_id from Alerte", mySQLConnection);

        myDataAdapter->InsertCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("insert into Alerte (motif,dateAlerte," +
            "fixee,nomPoste,nomApplication,nomFichier,FichierModel_id) values (@motif,@dateAlerte," +
            "@fixee,@nomPoste,@nomApplication,@nomFichier,@FichierModel_id)", mySQLConnection);

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@motif", SqlDbType::VarChar));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "motif";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@dateAlerte", SqlDbType::VarChar));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "dateAlerte";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@fixee", SqlDbType::Bit));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "fixee";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@nomPoste", SqlDbType::VarChar));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "nomPoste";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@nomApplication", SqlDbType::VarChar));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "nomApplication";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@nomFichier", SqlDbType::VarChar));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "nomFichier";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        myParameter = myDataAdapter->InsertCommand->Parameters->Add(
            gcnew SqlParameter("@FichierModel_id", SqlDbType::Int));
        myParameter->SourceColumn = "FichierModel_id";
        myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;

        time_t now = time(0);
        tm ltm;
        localtime_s(&ltm,&now);
        std::stringstream dateAjoutSysteme;
        dateAjoutSysteme << ltm.tm_mday
            << "/"
            << 1 + ltm.tm_mon
            << "/"
            << 1900 + ltm.tm_year
            << " "
            << 1 + ltm.tm_hour
            << ":"
            << 1 + ltm.tm_min
            << ":"
            << 1 + ltm.tm_sec;
        String^ str = gcnew System::String(dateAjoutSysteme.str().c_str());

        Boolean fixee = true;

        myDataAdapter->Fill(myDataSet, "Alerte");
        myRow = myDataSet->Tables["Alerte"]->NewRow();
        myRow->ItemArray[0] = "A";
        myRow->ItemArray[1] = str;
        myRow->ItemArray[2] = fixee;
        myRow->ItemArray[3] = "B";
        myRow->ItemArray[4] = "C";
        myRow->ItemArray[5] = "D";
        myRow->ItemArray[6] = 0UL;
        myDataSet->Tables["Alerte"]->Rows->Add(myRow);

        //we use insertcommand property for the update.
        myDataAdapter->Update(myDataSet, "Alerte");
    }
    catch (Exception ^ e) {
        Console::Write(e->ToString());
    }
    __finally {
        mySQLConnection->Close();
        system("PAUSE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert
>   the value NULL into column 'fixee', table 'MonitoringN.dbo.Alerte';
>   column does not allow nulls.

Any brilliant idea, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do a select * on Alerte ... so you don't know the order of columns ... then you assign values due to the column index ... I guess there is the problem ... fixee is probably not the 2nd column in myDataSet->Tables["Alerte"]

Comment: That's right, I've an ID column that comes first in Alerte's table which is auto-generated so I can't insert it, that's why I'm not initializing its value. Then, I've updated my code `myDataAdapter->SelectCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("select motif,dateAlerte,fixee,nomPoste," + "nomApplication,nomFichier,FichierModel_id from Alerte", mySQLConnection); and I've got the same error.`

Comment: hmmm ... have you tried to assign the values by name to your myRow? in c# it should work like this: myRow["fixee"] = true; ... and have you looked and your table after you inserted the new row in the debugger?

Comment: does it work when you delete lines like this: myParameter->SourceVersion = DataRowVersion::Current;
? I don't think it's useful here ...